# Xpath expression equal doesn't work but greater than does?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I need to filter on the type of car from my xml but it keeps giving me the error "Expected '}'" TYPE.

xml file

```
<CATALOG>
  <CAR>
    <TYPE>SUV</TYPE>
    <PRICE>20000</PRICE>
  </CAR>
</CATALOG>
```

I get the error when trying this:

```
XPath=/CATALOG/CAR[TYPE='SUV']
```

But this works:

```
XPath=/CATALOG/CAR[PRICE>10000]
```

So I only get the error when using equal

EDIT:
This is the code I use to show the items:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxCar" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CarDataSource},      
                                                    XPath=/CATALOG/CAR[TYPE='SUV']}"
                 ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource carTemplate}" />
```

xml has updated but was correct in file.

Comment: Can you share your code. Also your XML looks not valid.

Comment: Post your code please. This isn't related to WPF in any case. And yes, this is invalid XML - `<PRICE>` isn't followed by `</PRICE>`

Comment: I think it is because of your xml please check your xml validation see :
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Comment: @SubZero update the question and post your code. This is XAML though not code. And *please* fix your XML.

Comment: I'd definitely recommend trying to reproduce this in a console app explicitly executing the XPath - it'll be much easier for anyone to help you.

Comment: </CATALOG should be </CATALOG> (maybe just a copy/paste issue in the window)  Also, spit balling, meaning haven't test/tried it:  /CATALOG/CAR/TYPE[text() = 'SUV'] and your original works (/CATALOG/CAR[TYPE='SUV']) via test sight:  https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output

Comment: No repro with XmlDocument and `SelectSingleNode(@"/CATALOG/CAR[TYPE='SUV']")`. This returns the entire car element.

Comment: `XPath=/CATALOG/CAR[TYPE='SUV']` is *not* valid XAML syntax though. This is supposed to be a string. It should be `XPath="/CATALOG/CAR[TYPE='SUV']"`. That's what the error complains about - it found something that it couldn't parse until it reached the end of the Binding tag. [The documentation example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-bind-to-xml-data-using-an-xmldataprovider-and-xpath-queries) shows how to write XPath statements

Comment: If you get an error, then tell us what the error is: that's where diagnosis starts!